# Is it possible to install LunchBox Ornaments for use in rmarkdown with knitr?

Tags: fonts, latex, r-markdown, knitr

I wonder if it is possible to install and use this LunchBox Ornaments font, or any other, for use in rmarkdown with knitr to generate documents with latex.

Comment: If you use lualatex or xelatex you can use whatever font you have installed on your computer

Comment: And with pdflatex?

Comment: @JoséCarlos No, only xelatex or lualatex

Comment: Do yourself a favour and use lualatex or xelatex if you want special fonts. You shouldn't even notice any difference to pdflatex.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Xd, we were really near ;)

Comment: @manro yes :):) two seconds

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Could be a collision ;)

Comment: @manro I'll put a safety helmet on before visiting this site the next time :)

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz You should add a duck in the modern helmet too ```special forces duck``` When i will start to learn Tikz - i will toy with your ducks, cool package ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Header will look something like this:

```
---
title: "Hello World"
header-includes:    
- \usepackage{fontspec}
- \setmainfont{LunchBoxOrnaments}

output:
  pdf_document: 
       latex_engine: xelatex
---
```

**It is "Hello world", ha-ha ;)**

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to use LunchBoxOrnaments to include only one ornament in a specific place in the document and setting latex_engine: pdflatex?

Comment: @JoséCarlos no. You need to use xelatex or lualatex. But you can make a pic and after simply include into your Rmarkdown.